# Pandas: Count Distinct Combinations of two columns and add to Same Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, count, size, aggregation

Need help in adding the unique combination of two columns to the same dataframe in pandas.
I want that "nos" column.

```
Input:
id  acct_nos name
1   1a       one
1   1a       two
2   2b       three
3   3a       four
3   3b       five
3   3c       six
3   3d       seven
```

Here is the output I want:

```
Output:
id  acct_nos    nos name
1   1a          1   one 
1   1a          1   two
2   2b          1   three
3   3a          4   four
3   3b          4   five
3   3c          4   six
3   3d          4   seven
```

In the above example 
Id=1 has only 1 acct_nos-1a so the nos has to have a value 1.
Id=3 has only 4 acct_nos-3a to 3d so the nos has to have a value 4.

Not sure how to put this in Python Pandas. SQL queries I can figure out.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `groupby.transform` with `nunique()` function to count the number of unique elements per *id*:

```
df['nos'] = df.groupby("id")['acct_nos'].transform("nunique")
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

***option 1***

```
df.assign(nos=df.id.map(df.drop_duplicates(['id', 'acct_nos']).id.value_counts()))
```

***option 2***
Using `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

tups = pd.unique(
    zip(df.id.values.tolist(), df.acct_nos.values.tolist())
).tolist()
df.assign(nos=df.id.map(Counter([tup[0] for tup in tups])))

   id acct_nos   name  nos
0   1       1a    one    1
1   1       1a    two    1
2   2       2b  three    1
3   3       3a   four    4
4   3       3b   five    4
5   3       3c    six    4
6   3       3d  seven    4
```

Comment: Thank You piRsquared for taking time to get answer to this. I would have never thought of so many options.

Comment: @Arpit no problem, I think it's important to show the diversity of methods that exist to solve the same problem.